# Is there a way to pass data from a JSON object as a Integer and not a string?

Tags: json, node.js, ejs

I'm creating a small web app for a tabletop group I GM and am running into some difficulty. I have a JSON file passing data into my EJS template, but have two values in the same object that need to combine when displayed on the page.

```
// JSON
"Stat1": {
   "StartingStat": "2",
   "BonusStats": "3"
}
```

I would like when displayed on the webpage for this to display as "5" and I can't seem to find a way to pass through both values and then add them together.

If anyone has any advice I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: How about `<%= parseInt(Stat1.StartingStat, 10) + parseInt(Stat1.BonusStats, 10); %>`?

Comment: Thanks! Between your comment and Raghav's I was able to solve my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the JSON you have constructed,the values for StartingStat and BonusStats are given as Strings.
Constructing a JSON as given below would solve your problem

```
 // JSON
"Stat1": {
   "StartingStat": 2,
   "BonusStats": 3
}
```

:)